Many to one relationship results in UNIQUE constraint failing
I have two entities, DeviceTestResult and DeviceTestType, in a many to one relationship - that is, a DeviceTestResult has a single DeviceTestType & DeviceTestType has many DeviceTestResults.
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, Session

class DeviceTestType(Base):
    Base = declarative_base()
    __tablename__ = "device_test_type"
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255))
    test_results: Mapped[list["DeviceTestResult"]] = relationship(
        back_populates="test_type"
    )
    idx: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

class DeviceTestResult(Base):
    __tablename__ = "device_test"
    count = 0
    test_type: Mapped[DeviceTestType] = relationship(back_populates="test_results")
    test_type_idx: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey("device_test_type.idx"),
    )

I have a class DeviceTester that generates a DeviceTestResult. DeviceTestType is dynamically generated here - the primary key is based on device product IDs, test names & so on. This class is intended to be implemented by a user such that different test implementations can be written for different devices.
class DeviceTester:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_type = DeviceTestType(idx='0006969') # primary key.idx is generated dynamically based on device parameters

    def run_test(self):
        result = DeviceTestResult(test_type=self.test_type)
        return result

The reason why I dynamically generate the test type (instead of injecting it as a dependency to DeviceTester) is so that:

A new test type can be added by simply creating a new class (as opposed to having to add it to the database first)
No querying before creating the DeviceTester is necessary. I was running into problems with detached instances using this technique

The problem arises when you have multiple instances of DeviceTester:
test_1 = DeviceTester().run_test()
test_2 = DeviceTester().run_test()
test_3 = DeviceTester().run_test()

with Session() as session:
    session.add_all([test_1, test_2, test_3])
    session.commit()

This results in a IntegrityError - constraint failed: device_test_type.idx.
What is happening here is that SQLAlchemy is interpreting the DeviceTestType associated with each DeviceTestResult as separate objects with the same primary key, which obviously causes the unique constraint to fail. This is reflected in the code as well - the DeviceTestType objects all have only one associated DeviceTestResult (instead of the expected three).
I've tried:

Using session.merge
Using session.no_autoflush
Creating a helper function that creates a single DeviceTestType object & sets all DeviceTestResult to point to this object

None of these seem to work.
Does anyone have any insight into fixing this issue?
I'm aware that my solution of dynamically generating DeviceTestType may not be appropriate, so I would also appreciate feedback on that.

I'm not sure what the complexity of computing the test_type_idx is but I made up a contrived example.  Probably the easiest thing would be to just accumulate the unique test types and then "upsert" them before adding and flushing/committing the DeviceTestResult objects. Documentation orm-upsert-statements
I'm not sure how DeviceTester is supposed to work but it sounded like the strategy pattern so I made something up like that in this example.
Here is the contrived example:
import os
from dataclasses import dataclass

from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    ForeignKey,
    String,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import (
    func,
    select,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    Session,
    relationship,
    DeclarativeBase,
    Mapped,
    mapped_column
)
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert


def get_engine(env):
    return create_engine(
        f"postgresql+psycopg2://{env['DB_USER']}:{env['DB_PASSWORD']}@{env['DB_HOST']}:{env['DB_PORT']}/{env['DB_NAME']}",
        echo=True,
    )


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class DeviceTestType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'device_test_type'
    idx: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255))
    test_results: Mapped[list["DeviceTestResult"]] = relationship(
        back_populates="test_type"
    )


class DeviceTestResult(Base):
    __tablename__ = "device_test"
    idx: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    # Should this be mapped?
    count: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(server_default='0')
    test_type: Mapped[DeviceTestType] = relationship(back_populates="test_results")
    test_type_idx: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey("device_test_type.idx"),
    )


class ForkTest:
    def run(self, spec, test_type_idx, **context):
        # Do something
        #...
        # Just link with the idx but don't flush yet.
        return DeviceTestResult(test_type_idx=test_type_idx, count=3)

class ThreadTest:
    def run(self, spec, test_type_idx, **context):
        # Do something
        #...
        # Just link with the idx but don't flush yet.
        return DeviceTestResult(test_type_idx=test_type_idx, count=100)


@dataclass
class TestSpec:
    os: str
    arch: str
    cores: int
    strat: str


@dataclass
class TestRunnerService:

    db: object
    strategy_registry: object

    def compute_test_type_dict(self, spec):
        #@NOTE: This assumes this is deterministic
        return dict(
            idx=f"dtt-{spec.os}-{spec.arch}-{spec.cores}-{spec.strat}",
            name=f"{spec.os} {spec.arch} {spec.cores} {spec.strat}",
        )

    def upsert_test_types(self, test_type_dicts):
        # Insert the device test type, if there one already exists then just do nothing.
        stmt = insert(DeviceTestType).values(test_type_dicts).on_conflict_do_nothing(index_elements=[DeviceTestType.idx]).returning(DeviceTestType)
        return self.db.scalars(stmt, execution_options={"populate_existing": True})

    def run_tests(self, specs):
        test_type_dicts = {}
        results = []
        for spec in specs:
            test_type_dict = self.compute_test_type_dict(spec)
            if test_type_dict['idx'] not in test_type_dicts:
                test_type_dicts[test_type_dict['idx']] = test_type_dict
            testing_strategy = self.strategy_registry[spec.strat]
            result = testing_strategy.run(spec, test_type_idx=test_type_dict['idx'], db=self.db)
            results.append(result)

        # Upsert these first, this allows multiple runs without duplicating
        # the test types.
        self.upsert_test_types(list(test_type_dicts.values()))

        # Now record all our results.
        self.db.add_all(results)
        return results


def print_counts(db):
    counts = dict(
        types=db.scalar(select(func.count(DeviceTestType.idx))),
        results=db.scalar(select(func.count(DeviceTestResult.idx))))
    for k, v in counts.items():
        print (f"{k}={v}")


def main():
    engine = get_engine(os.environ)

    with engine.begin() as conn:
        Base.metadata.create_all(conn)

    FORK_REPEATS = 3
    THREAD_REPEATS = 2
    test_specs = sum([
        [TestSpec(
                os="linux",
                arch="amd64",
                cores=4,
                strat="fork",
            )] * FORK_REPEATS,
        [TestSpec(
                os="linux",
                arch="amd64",
                cores=8,
                strat="thread",
            )] * THREAD_REPEATS
    ], [])
    for spec in test_specs:
        print (f"{spec}")
    strategy_registry = {
        "fork": ForkTest(),
        "thread": ThreadTest(),
    }
    with Session(engine) as db:
        test_runner_service = TestRunnerService(db, strategy_registry)
        test_runner_service.run_tests(test_specs)
        db.commit()

    # Read back results and see what happens.
    with Session(engine) as db:
        print_counts(db)

    with Session(engine) as db:
        test_runner_service = TestRunnerService(db, strategy_registry)
        test_runner_service.run_tests(test_specs)
        db.commit()

    # Read back results and see what happens.
    with Session(engine) as db:
        print_counts(db)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Is there a dialect agnostic alternative to on_conflict_do_nothing?

I think sqlite/postgresql have this similar feature and mysql can fallback to just updating the idx to itself which essentially does nothing, ie. on_duplicate_key_update.  Does app specifically require agnostic or are you just using another db?

@frimann I added a doc link to the answer that has more information about those 3 dialects.

agnostic is a nice to have. At minimum I'd need to support SQLite & Postgres, & it looks like I can just use a switch (if) statement to select the appropriate upsert strategy. Thanks for your help, I will try out your solution & see if it works.
